# Doing a Python 3 Exercise:

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a function with the following header to format the integer with the specified width.
def format(number, width):
The function returns a string for the number with prefix 0s. The size of the string is the width. 
For example, format(34, 4) returns "0034" and format(34, 5) returns "00034". If the number is longer than the width, the function returns the string representation for the number. For example, format(34, 1) returns "34".
Write a test program that prompts the user to enter a number and its width and dis- plays a string returned from invoking format(number, width).

Example: 
Enter an integer: 453
Enter the width: 6
The formatted number is: 000453

Answer (score 1):

So, this program would only take a little mental math.

```
def format(number, width):
    number = str(number)
    numZeros = width - len(number)
    return "0" * numZeroes + number
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `def format()`, it shadows the built-in.

Here is your function:

```
def myformat(number, width):
    length = len(str(number))
    return "0"*(width-length)+str(number)
```

---

```
myformat(34, 4)
=> '0034'
myformat(321, 5)
=> '00321'
myformat(321, 3)
=> '321'
myformat(321, 2)
=> '321'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do.

```
enter code here

def nformat(number,width):
    width_1 = '0' + str(width) + 'd'
    print("The Formatted number is ",format(number,width_1))


def main():
    num1 = eval(input("Enter an integer: "))
    num2 = eval(input("Enter the width: "))
    nformat(num1,num2)
```